# Creating pdf on Firestore with Pdfplum: Template path "no such object"

Tags: firebase, pdf, firebase-extensions

I installed the Pdfplum-Firebase-extension "Generate PDFs with Firestore" on the Firebase-server.

When installing, you are asked for a template-path. I used my default bucked in which I created a folder called "pdfplum":

[image]

In Storage:

[image]

When I trigger the extension, I get the error:

`Error ApiError: No such object: hauzr01.appspot.com/pdfplum`

I can't figure out how to solve this. Can anybody help?

The documentation says to use "gs://..." before the path, but then I get the error "No valid path".